# User messaging system

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking at creating a user messaging system (similar to Facebook).

What I want to know is essentially what should the table structure look like? The requirements I have are as follows:

- Messages are exchanged between users - a sender can select multiple users to send a message to.
- Messages are displayed in a thread-style layout, as a 1-1 conversation. i.e. each recipient's reply will appear in it's own thread.
- Individual messages cannot be deleted, however a thread can be deleted. Deleting a thread doesn't delete any messages, it just removes that thread from the user's inbox. However the other user can still access the thread if he/she hasn't deleted it from his/her inbox.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
Table messages
==============
id (PK)
user_id (from)
subject
body
sent_at


Table message_recipients
========================
message_id (PK)
user_id (PK)
read_status
```

EDIT: What about the following:

```
Table messages
==============
id (PK)
thread_id   
user_id (from)
body
sent_at


Table threads
=============
id (PK)
user_id (from)
subject


Table thread_recipients
=======================
thread_id (PK)
user_id (PK)
read_status
sender_deleted
recipient_deleted
```

Comment: There is probably more information than is possible to give. I don't think anyone is going to fully design your database for you (at least not for free). Why don't you tell us what your thoughts are, so we can respond with opinions.

Comment: @Dutchie432 - I'm not asking for a full database design - I'm just after some guidance. The messaging system is just a module for my existing system, i.e. I already have a users table. I've updated my question anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest having the following at least:

Users, Threads, Messages

- All messages would have a thread

  - foreign key: thread_id
- All threads would have at least one message and at least one recipient (as well as sender)

  - foreign key: to_user_id, from_user_id, message_id

From there you could simply assign a couple flags to your thread (to_user_deleted, from_user_deleted) that would be updated accordingly.

There a lot more things to consider of course, such what kinds of things you want to account for. For example:

- Do you want to display the current message as opposed to the starting message?
- Do you want to allow users to mark individual messages as read, or just threads?

You need to take all of these into account while designing your database.

Comment: Thanks for the response Angelo - much appreciated. I'm not sure what you mean by "do you want display the current message as opposed to the starting message" - as it's a thread based layout then it would show all messages I think. Regarding whether to mark individual messages or threads as read, I think it should be the actual thread. So in the thread table there could be a flag for "read_status".

Comment: Don't forget, you'll need a read_status for each user. Also, I meant when you give the user an overview of their messages (if you are planning on giving them one) would you display an excerpt from the first message or the most recent? Think of a webmail interface where they give you a little excerpt of the messages within the email. It's the kind of thing you don't NEED to have, but it is something to think about.

Comment: Cheers. Please can you see my latest edit and let me know what you think.

Comment: Do you think the initial message should be included in the 'threads' table? That way if the same message is sent to multiple recipients then a separate message doesn't need to be created for each recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like Jabber (example: [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) or [Web Client](http://www.jwchat.org/))

If you need PHP to interact with it you could use something like:

http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/ or http://code.google.com/p/jaxl/

Comment: It looks like he's trying to design a private messaging system as opposed to an actual in-site chat.

Answer (score 0):

@Angelo R. Would like to know why we require the Thread Table? This isn't any discussion board. If you want to retrieve the whole thread/conversation of messages you can simply query by source AND recipient ID.
Plus, if you use Thread, nothing bad. But what in this situation
If new message - new thread_id (automatically created), If replied to existing conversation, you have the thread_id, but what if you are creating a new message (say like facebook popup), you don't know whether there was any previous conversation or if thread_id is available or not unless you execute a special query to it.
This was my thought. Tell me if I might be wrong somewhere.